Argo workflow retry a workflow using rest service
I am trying to rerun an Argo Workflow through REST endpoint call. However it says it is Not implemented. Does anyone know how to get around this? And when would this be implemented? As per apidocs.
The below should be the endpoint.
e.g.
curl https://localhost:2746/api/v1/workflows/argo/example-wf-template/retry --insecure
{"code":12,"message":"Not Implemented"}

The Argo version I am using is: v3.5.10
Any insights would be helpful. I also do not want to use command line tools in the code.

As per the API documentation the request should be a PUT request, so it should be:
curl -X PUT https://localhost:2746/api/v1/workflows/argo/example-wf-template/retry --insecure

